# RangeError: minimumFractionDigits value is out of range. Chart.js

Tags: charts, react-chartjs

using react-chartjs-2 to use ChartJS in my NextJS project. Was working fine, then I did some component refactoring/cleanup and everything broke, and when I tried to go back, it still didnt work. Here is my code. I've tried reinstalling Chartjs, react-chartjs, checking the docs for this error. Thought it was an error with my options, but I completely removed the options from my data too, just left the data, and copied the data that was in the sample doc. This error also occurs with my line chart as well.

```
import { Radar } from "react-chartjs-2";
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  RadialLinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Filler,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
} from "chart.js";

ChartJS.register(
  RadialLinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Filler,
  Tooltip,
  Legend
);

interface BallAnalyticsGraphProps {}

const BallAnalyticsGraph: React.FC<BallAnalyticsGraphProps> = ({}) => {
  const data = {
    labels: ["Thing 1", "Thing 2", "Thing 3", "Thing 4", "Thing 5", "Thing 6"],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "# of Votes",
        data: [2, 9, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      },
      {
        label: "Sample",
        data: [2, 9, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      },
    ],
  };

  return <Radar data={data} />;
};

export default BallAnalyticsGraph;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed my issue. I was using the following to change the font in a different chartjs component, but it was making changed globally, and thus causing the error.

```
ChartJS.defaults.font = {
   family: "Segoe UI",
 };
```