# Error "RangeError: minimumFractionDigits value is out of range" with ChartJS in Next.js app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to create an application using [react-chartjs-2.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chartjs-2)
It works locally but in production, it gives the following error:

```
Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information).
```

Here's my browser error[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvYLH.png)

```
framework-7751730b10fa0f74.js:9 
        
       RangeError: minimumFractionDigits value is out of range.
    at new NumberFormat (<anonymous>)
    at 389-ed817b9827d847c5.js:11:22041
    at e3 (389-ed817b9827d847c5.js:11:22084)
    at e1.numeric (3fff1979-b3fd6dd997b88037.js:6:36399)
    at g (389-ed817b9827d847c5.js:6:4424)
    at e1.generateTickLabels (3fff1979-b3fd6dd997b88037.js:6:44125)
    at e1._convertTicksToLabels (3fff1979-b3fd6dd997b88037.js:6:47183)
    at e1.update (3fff1979-b3fd6dd997b88037.js:6:41586)
    at tp (3fff1979-b3fd6dd997b88037.js:6:66794)
    at Object.update (3fff1979-b3fd6dd997b88037.js:6:69634)
um @ framework-7751730b10fa0f74.js:9
main-e7a7892cb0edc024.js:1 
        
       RangeError: minimumFractionDigits value is out of range.
    at new NumberFormat (<anonymous>)
    at 389-ed817b9827d847c5.js:11:22041
    at e3 (389-ed817b9827d847c5.js:11:22084)
    at e1.numeric (3fff1979-b3fd6dd997b88037.js:6:36399)
    at g (389-ed817b9827d847c5.js:6:4424)
    at e1.generateTickLabels (3fff1979-b3fd6dd997b88037.js:6:44125)
    at e1._convertTicksToLabels (3fff1979-b3fd6dd997b88037.js:6:47183)
    at e1.update (3fff1979-b3fd6dd997b88037.js:6:41586)
    at tp (3fff1979-b3fd6dd997b88037.js:6:66794)
    at Object.update (3fff1979-b3fd6dd997b88037.js:6:69634)
J @ main-e7a7892cb0edc024.js:1
main-e7a7892cb0edc024.js:1 
        
       A client-side exception has occurred, see here for more info: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/client-side-exception-occurred
```

And here's my code

```
import React from "react";

import { Line } from "react-chartjs-2";
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
} from "chart.js";

ChartJS.register(
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend
);
export const options = {
  responsive: true,
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      position: "top",
    },
    title: {
      display: false,
    },
  },
};

const labels = [
  "Monday",
  "Tuesday",
  "Wednesday",
  "Thursday",
  "Friday",
  "Saturday",
  "Sunday",
];
export const data = {
  labels,
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "Weekley Data",
      data: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70],
      borderColor: "rgb(255, 99, 132)",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)",
    },
  ],
};

function Components() {
  return (
    <div style={{ width: "80%" }}>
      <Line options={options} data={data} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Components;
```

It works fine on `localhost:3000` in the development environment however it breaks in a production environment / when deployed to the server.

Can anyone help me understand and fix this issue?

Comment: what does the browser console say?

Comment: I have updated my question with the error @AndréAlçadaPadez

Comment: When you get an issue that only happens in deployment, you should try to replicate it locally by running a `build` and then a `serve`. It'll make it easier to debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a version problem between your nextJS version and your ChartJS version.

For example, I was on nextJS `12.3.1` and chartJS `4.0.1`. Switching to `12.3.2-canary.10` OR switch back to chartJS `2.9.4` fixed it for me.

You can also put `swcMinify: false` instead of `true` in your `next.config.js` but this is a temporary fix and will slow down your build time.

Comment: Upgrading to `next@12.3.4` and `chart.js@4.2.1` still not work. But `swcMinify: false` works.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer [here](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/10673)

just add `swcMinify: false` in `next.config.js`

Answer (score 0):

From what i found online, tat error occurs when you're running incompatible versions of Chart.js / react-charts.

> Nevermind, I found the problem. The problem was I was using v3.1 Chart.js, while trying to use settings from v3.5 Chart.js.
> Changed the JS file version and now it's working well.

from https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chartjs-2:

> We recommend using chart.js@^3.0.0.

Try to see if you're running the correct versions...

Another possible solution:

[RangeError: minimumFractionDigits value is out of range. Chart.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71415227/)

Comment: Tried but it didn't work